# Why Outlook cannot redirect some emails via rule but ok via forwarding?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email, redirection

I bumped into this weird situation - one outlook and one hotmail accounts, want to redirect incoming emails for hotmail account to outlook account, so I have tried these two options individually:

- Enable forwarding - this worked for **ALL** incoming emails
  [image: Enable forwarding]
- Rule (with "Redirect to" action) - this worked for some incoming emails (e.g. emails from gmail) but some not
  [image: Redirect rule]

What could be the possible reason why some emails worked but some not with the "Redirect to" action but **ALL** emails worked with the Enable forwarding setting? Even those failed in the "Redirect to" action worked in the Enable forwarding setting!

I've already eliminated the possibility of a wrong rule setting because I added two actions in the rule: one "Redirect to" and one "Move to folder", the "Move to folder" action executed for **ALL** emails, but the "Redirect to" action executed for some but not all.

As to why I have a working Enable forwarding setting yet I still want the rule, is so that I can selectively choose which emails to apply the rule, instead of applying to all.

P.S. Although I am showing the Outlook client, I was not doing some client side rule, I was doing server side rule.

Answer (score 1):

Your Issue is the basic issue of any mail redirection to a different domain:

Let's consider to be:

- (A) the original sender of the email
- (B) the forwarding / redirecting  account
- (C) the end receiver.

Forwarding and Redirecting are two completely different actions:

- **Forwarding** will create a new email based on the body of the original message (with some lines added about the original sender), but with a new header, in which the `From:` field will contain (B)'s email address. And as sending server will result (B)'s mail server.
- **Redirecting** on the other hand, will take the original email, make some modifications to the header, and send it to (C)'s mail server. In the `From:` field will result (A), but as final sending server will still result (B)'s mail server.

Now, the issue is that in a redirected email, (C)'s server will see an incoherence between the `From:` field and the server from which it is receiving the email. Here's where the [Sender Policy Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) (SPF) comes in. In short, the SPF record of (A)'s server determines which are the allowed senders for (A)'s email address: usually, (B)'s server will not be mentioned in (A)'s SPF records. This means that on server (C) the SPF for a redirected email will almost always fail. If server (A) has a tolerant SPF policy ("consider mail server (A) to be correct, but allow others, too"), the email will be delivered anyway. But if (A) enforces a strict SPF policy ("only allow emails from mail server (A)"), (C) will reject the email with a SPF hard fail.

The next issue is, that if the redirected email bounces from server (C), (B) will never know of it, because the bounce will be delivered to the original sender (A). This can be mitigated with SRS ([Sender Rewriting Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme)), where server (B) modifies the header in a way to receive the bounces from redirected messages. Microsoft does not implement SRS (at least not in free email services), as [can be read in this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/spf-error-with-auto-forwarding/6d3b13b0-8c0c-425a-b5f8-2ea1fbf35263); their official stance is "Use forwarding."  [This other thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/forwarded-emails-bounce-because-of-spf-record/96a86cad-33f9-4ae9-b549-3c6dd19c1138) describes an issue similar as yours.

From the above considerations, since you have no way to influence the SPF record of (A), it results that **a redirection rule can only be safely used in two cases**:

1. (B) and (C) are on the same mail server. The redirect will be handled as copying a message between two inboxes. (Please note that this might still not always work for very large providers such as hotmail, outlook, gmail etc for internal policy reasons).
2. You are the owner of (C)'s mail server and can totally whitelist address (B).

Last but not least it should also be mentioned that mail server (C) can have different SPAM policies than (B), so for such reason it might just anyway refuse a message that (B) might instead allow.

[Further Reading](https://support.valimail.com/support/solutions/articles/48001178733-problems-you-may-see-due-to-forwarders-and-what-to-do)

Comment: Thanks heaps! Totally makes sense! Almost a perfect explanation to my situation, except there are two "forwarding" options in Outlook: 1 rule action and 1 global forward as shown in my question. The 1 in rule action matches what you said (changes sender/From: to B, title added "FW:", original email quoted). However, the 1 I shown, although it says "forwarding", it still shows A as the sender/From: and no "FW:" added in title and original email content as is, so it behaves like a "redirect", hence my question: same sender A/SPF can "global forward" but not via redirect action in Outlook, why?

Comment: BTW I also tried the "forwarding" rule action, just like you said, it works for all emails. Just that I don't like it changing the original sender in the "From:" so I am not using it.

Comment: @user1589188 Your first comment: Some hosting providers use "forward" to indicate "redirect", and in fact on your first screenshot is indicated a global redirect, not a global forward. Maybe on the web version that's different. But the name doesn't matter, it's the principle which matters. The answer remains the same: if the "from" field isn't changed, you will run into SPF issues

Comment: Exactly my point: this global "forward"(redirect), which does not change the "From:", worked on all emails, no SPF issue! But the redirect action in rule, which also does not change the "From:", DID NOT work on every email. Same email that failed in the redirect action, worked on this global "forward"(redirect).

Answer (score 0):

Are forwarding rules enabled when I run a redirect rule?

This is expected behavior. Forwarding on a mailbox overrides an inbox redirection rule. To enable the redirection rule, remove forwarding on the mailbox.
For more details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/inbox-redirect-rule-not-working.

Comment: Thanks for checking, I am aware of that, I tried them (Enable forwarding and rule) separately. And as I said, one of the actions in the rule worked for ALL emails, just not the "redirecting to" action for some emails.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with your Outlook desktop client and Outlook web app?

Comment: Can't comment on the client as I don't care. I tried in the browser with online web app and the issue is there.

Comment: According to my tests, when you create a forward or redirect rule, you can add more than one address to send to. The number of addresses you can send to may be limited, depending on the settings for your account. If you add more addresses than are allowed, your rule won’t work.

Comment: Yeah may be. But I was only testing 1 email address

Comment: Please try changing account tests to check if there is the same issue. It can be caused by an account issue.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? Please feel free to drop us a note if there is any update.